# Spring Bean Extensions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I have a Spring MVC project with a generic application context xml file. This file defines the generic configuration of my applciation such as the base property file for i18n and data source to connect to the database and so on. While i define this context file i also want to define the session factory which will have base configurations such as the data source to use, the second level caching (eh-cache) and so on. But this will not contain the list of entity beans that my application would load. I want to keep the mapping of the entity beans only in separate file and load them based on need.

Is there a possibility to extend the session factory that i had defined in the base file and only add the additional entity beans? I will eventually have several spring configuration files which will load a separate set of entities. can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

There are several posibilities.

- You can use `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` to externalize the entity list to a property file. (You can use SPEL in the property file).
- You can use an abstract bean definition and use it as parent in other sessionFactory beans, then you can import  thems based on a `Enviroment` `PropertySource`.

Note that Hibernate `SessionFactory` is inmutable after building it and `SessionFactoryBean` build `SessionFactory` in `afterPropertiesSet` method so the work of setting up the `SessionFactoryBean` that you want must be done by some `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`

**EDIT**

After reading your comment, I think that you could declare a `EntityClassHolder` bean and use the Autowire collections facility to get all entities in a `EntityClassFactoryBean` that you can inject in a single `SessionFactoryBean`. But i don't sure if that is that you want to do:

```
public class EntityClassHolder {

  List<Class<?>> entityClasses;

  public List<Class<?>> getEntityClasses() {
    return entityClasses;
  }

  public void setEntityClasses(List<Class<?>> entityClasses) {
    this.entityClasses = entityClasses;
  }
}



  public class EntityClassFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<List<Class<?>>> {

    @Autowired
    List<EntityClassHolder> list; 

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return List.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Class<?>> createInstance() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Class<?>> classList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        for (EntityClassHolder ech : list) {
            classList.addAll(ech.getEntityClasses());
        }

        return classList;
    }
}
```

Now, if you have several applicatonContext-xxx.xml for example, the `SessionFactory` will be configured with entity classes definied in `EntityClassHolder` beans when you load one of them.

Comment: Thanks Jose for inputs. I was able to achieve the SessionFactory extension through parents bean extension mechanism. However, this creates multiple session factories. Can I use the same sessionfactory and some how add the additional entity bean references only? I am not sure if multiple session factories will cause problems.

Comment: The idea was to load a single SessionFactory, choosing which of them through configuration.

Comment: But jose, i have several independent modules which have to be loaded dynamically. The modules to be loaded itself is a run time configuration. I would need to reduce the total number of session factories created so that the overall performance of the system wont go down.. Also, is there a possibility to link me to some examples on how to achieve the PropertySource with reference to Hibernate Bean inclusions? I couldn't find any